# What do you call the open area outside of a building as depicted in the picture?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, north-american-english

I find it hard to name the place other than "an open area outside of a building." It doesn't matter if it is in the front or on any other side of the building.

[image]

Comment: Plaza, mall, square, common, court.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know common and mall can refer to this.

Comment: You need to edit the tags to add a tag specifying which branch of English you're asking about -- start typing "english" and you'll get a list to choose from. Don't choose "early-modern-english". Different countries use different words; British English would only use "square" from @HotLicks' list.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good tip.

Comment: . . . .  forecourt . . .  walkway

Comment: [_Very_ closely related: 'What do you call an area enclosed by apartment complex structures ... is it a court?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279979/what-do-you-call-an-area-enclosed-by-apartment-complex-structures-is-it-a-court/366224#366224).

Comment: @Andrew 'Plaza' isn't so rare (Google Ngrams seem to confirm my suspicions); perhaps the influence of the _Piccadilly Plaza_ here in Manchester has skewed this.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, I've read it. I think I'm more concerned with a more public space that is mostly outside of a commercial building in the urban area. Plaza is also my first thought.

Comment: plaza is the "modern" term.